# How to create dynamic NSImage for menubar item?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I want to create dynamic images containing text to assign them to menubar item icon. The text for image will be strings containing some data.

Now I set menubar item icon using this code:

```
    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(NSVariableStatusItemLength)

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

        if let button = statusItem.button {
            button.image = NSImage(named: "icon")
        }
    }
```

I tried to set text using `button.title` but I need two lines of text.

How to create and assign dynamic icons created from template image + text to the menubar item?